# Rspec, testing object receives method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an example of code not passing in test but working in the console.

Failing Test:

```
describe ImporterProfile do
  it 'sends defaults method to EventAttribute model' do 

    expect(ListPage).to receive(:new) #passes
    expect(EventAttribute).to receive(:new) #fails

    ImporterProfile.new.standard_profile

end

1) ImporterProfile standard_profile sends new method to associated objects
 Failure/Error: importer_profile.standard_profile
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/importer_profile.rb:51:in `standard_profile'
 # ./spec/models/importer_profile_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Models:

```
class ImporterProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :list_page, dependent: :delete
  has_many :event_attributes, dependent: :delete_all

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_page
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_attributes

  def standard_profile
    self.list_page = ListPage.new
    self.event_attributes = EventAttribute.new
  end
end


class EventAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :importer_profile
end


class ListPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :importer_profile
end
```

However, running this method in the console instantiates a new ImporterProfile, ListPage and several EventAttribute objects.

Anyone understand what is going on here?

Comment: Can you show the full content of the method `standard_profile` ?

Comment: That is all of it. It was more complex before but I paired it down to a small example and I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is that you are mocking `EventAttribute.new`, but only returning `nil`, so Rails can't enumerate the active records as is required by the `self.event_attributes =` statement. (It needs to set the foreign key attribute of the `EventAttribute` records to the id of the `ImporterProfile` record.)

If you don't mind continuing with execution, you can do:

```
expect(EventAttribute).to receive(:new).and_call_original
```

Alternatively, you can return a double, but you'll need to provide stubs for whatever methods `ActiveRecord` requires, either by using a library such as http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-active_record_mocks/versions/0.1.4 or by rolling your own.

As an aside, this question would have been a little easier to answer if you'd provided some way to associate the line numbers in the error stack trace with the sources you provided. Also, the comments on your `expect` statements that the first passes and the second fails is confusing because it appears that you are raising an error before the expectations are being checked.

Comment: It wouldn't be EventAttributes but rather EventAttribute.

Comment: The ImporterProfile has many EventAttributes, but in the method above only one EventAttribute is being initialized. EventAttribute.new doesn't return nil but rather an object with all nil attributes. I'll give your recommendation a try.

Comment: @DavidMoore I corrected the answer to say EventAttribute. Sorry about that. As for the initialize, yes you are only assigning one, but because your model includes a `has_many` association, Rails needs to _check_ to see how many are being assigned, which involves the `each` call to the object on the right hand side of the assignment. In any event, when I said that `EventAttribute.new` returned `nil`, I was referring to your test double, which does indeed return `nil` unless you include `.ane_return` or `and_continue`